# How to create a list of instances efficiently in java using a another list of instances

Tags: java, list, loops

I have a list of instances where I need to create another list of instances using the instances in the first list.
As the example shown below, I can use a foreach or a for loop. Is there a better way to do this more efficiently?

```
List<Mesage> messages; 
List<ArchMessage> archMessages = new ArrayList<>();
for(Message message : messages) {
       archMessages.add(new ArchMessage(message));
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `Message` and `ArcMessage` classes?

Comment: You haven't defined your problem/solution space clearly enough. What do you mean by efficiently?  More readable?  More maintainable?  Best performance?  Most scalable?

Comment: Are there other ways to do this?  Yes.  More efficiently?  No.

Comment: @PM77-1 `ArchMessage` means the archived `Message`.

Comment: @scottb what I meant by efficiently is the best performance and scalable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java 8 `Stream`s:

```
List<ArchMessage> archMessages =
    messages.stream()
            .map(message -> new ArchMessage(message))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<ArchMessage> archMessages =
    messages.stream()
            .map(ArchMessage::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

That's as efficient as it gets but let's say your code could benefit from parallelism then using the streams API would be ideal as we can get parallelism for free 
by using `parallelStream` e.g.

```
 List<ArchMessage> resultSet = messages.parallelStream()
                                       .map(ArchMessage::new)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Other than that your current approach seems good and readable.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're unable to use streams from Java 8, Apache Commons Collections library provides the following:**

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/

```
Collection<ArchMessage> archMessages = CollectionUtils.collect(messages, new Transformer() {
    public Object transform(Object o) {
        return new ArchMessage((Mesage) o);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Feedback to your recherche:
I would recommend to don't use a foreach. It will throw your efficient down cause of an inner request at each. I would recommend to use a for each time..